# How to arrange data and its values vertically in html, and sum values up?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to write a webpage that users will know and calculate its value by choosing different options. The users can choose one from 'offer rank' and one from 'salary' and sum their values up to get 'total'. Currently I don't worry about how to calculate the 'total' by JavaScript. I'm just wroking on the html and css parts.

I followed Cucunber's idea. Currently my code is:

```css
<style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .body{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .wrapper {
            width: auto;
            max-width: 1000px;
            display: flex;
            border-top: 1px dashed black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .values {
            flex: 0 0 80%;
            display: flex;
        }

        .value {
            flex: 0 0 25%;
            padding: 10px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }

        .title {
            flex: 20%;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hans">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="title">BC jobs calculation</div>
            <div class="values">
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankA" name="rank" value="25" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank A &nbsp&nbsp<br>（include type 0）</b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 25 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankB" name="rank" value="10" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank B </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 10 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankC" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankD" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="title">offer rank</div>
            <div class="values">
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankA" name="rank" value="25" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank A &nbsp&nbsp（include type 0）</b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 25 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankB" name="rank" value="10" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank B </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 10 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankC" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankD" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    D </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankE" name="rank" value="25" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank E &nbsp&nbsp（include type 0）</b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 25 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankF" name="rank" value="10" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank F </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 10 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankG" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    G </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankH" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    H </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="title">result</div>
            <div class="values">
                <span class="value">
                    calc value
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>

</body>

</html>
```

The output should be like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    offer rank   NOC rank A     NOC rank B      NOC rank C      NOC rank D
                 25 marks       10 marks        5 marks         5 marks
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    salary       More than 100,000  50 marks    92,500-94,999  36 marks 
                 97,500-99,999      38 marks    90,000-92,499  35 marks
                 95,000-97,499      37 marks    87,500-89,999  34 marks
                 ...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    total        (calculated value)
```

But the output now is not what I fully expect. The rank A, B, C , D , E, F, G, H are in the same line. I expect C and D to be the next line (for salary). And I only can choose one selection from all of them instead of one from offer rank and one from salary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: flex` to make it looks like you want

`wrapper` is class which contains title and content
`values` is class which contains your options

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .body{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .wrapper {
            width: auto;
            max-width: 1000px;
            display: flex;
            border-top: 1px dashed black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .values {
            flex: 0 0 80%;
            display: flex; 
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .value {
            flex: 0 0 25%;
            padding: 10px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }

        .title {
            flex: 20%;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="title">offer rank</div>
            <div class="values">
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankA" name="rank" value="25" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank A &nbsp&nbsp（include type 0）</b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 25 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankB" name="rank" value="10" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank B </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 10 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankC" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankD" name="rank" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="title">offer rank</div>
            <div class="values">
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankA" name="rank2" value="25" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank A &nbsp&nbsp（include type 0）</b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 25 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankB" name="rank2" value="10" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC
                    rank B </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 10 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankC" name="rank2" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
                <span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankD" name="rank2" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
<span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankD" name="rank2" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
<span class="value"><input type="radio" id="rankD" name="rank2" value="5" onchange="getTotal()"> NOC rank
                    C </b><br><br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 5 marks</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="title">result</div>
            <div class="values">
                <span class="value">
                    calc value
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would you plz take a look of my updated question? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, as I understand your question, you should change "name" property of each input radio group. For example, all radio buttons at first line must have name "rank" and the second one should be "rank2". Also change code. To move your field to the line below use flex-wrap: wrap on the class values